# Fragment keeping its state after ondetach

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello i need a fragment to reset its state (set all **EditText** to empty) but its state keeps getting saved.
I set `super.onCreate(null);` in `onCreate` and even tried to set all **EditText** with `setText("")` in `onDetach()` which gets called correctly, i even tried to close the fragment from inside it with `getfragmentmanager().popbackstack()` or                 `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(MyFragment.this).commit();`

Still nothing, the fragments still has all its **EditText** to the previous state when replaced.

```
public class IngredienteComposerFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText mNameView;
private EditText mMinusPriceView;
private EditText mPlusPriceView;
private Button mSaveView;


public IngredienteComposerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static IngredienteComposerFragment newInstance() {
    IngredienteComposerFragment fragment = new IngredienteComposerFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ingrediente_composer, container, false);
    mNameView = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    mMinusPriceView = v.findViewById(R.id.minus_price);
    mPlusPriceView = v.findViewById(R.id.plus_price);
    mSaveView = v.findViewById(R.id.save);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSaveView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Ingrediente i = new Ingrediente(mNameView.getText().toString(), Double.parseDouble(mPlusPriceView.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(mMinusPriceView.getText().toString()));
            i.save();
//                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
//                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(IngredienteComposerFragment.this).commit();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mNameView.setText("");
    mMinusPriceView.setText("");
    mPlusPriceView.setText("");
    mSaveView.setOnClickListener(null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    EditText mNomeView = getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
    mNomeView.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imgr.showSoftInput(mNomeView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

}

in the activity i first load a fragment in the **FrameLayout** with:

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, portataComposerFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

then i load my fragment with

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, ingredienteComposerFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

After some tests i noticed that since i am using the following layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/name_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Nome"
                    android:saveEnabled="false"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    />
```

for my edittext, with **saveEnabled="false"** the state won't be saved, but still i would like to know why it's saved even when the fragment gets destroyed (it calls the onDetach method)

Comment: Post your fragment code please.

Comment: Hello, i posted the code.